# bug fixing in two fer program with js

Tags: javascript

how could I fix my js code?
this is the "two fer" program in "exersicm" but it has a problem in it
this is a description for my program :

Given a name, return a string with the message:
One for name, one for me.

Where "name" is the given name.

However, if the name is missing, return the string:
One for you, one for me.

```
export const twoFer = (name) => {

 if (name !== "" ) {
return("One for " + name+", one for me.")}
 else {
return("One for you, one for me.")}}
```

Comment: You are using `console.log()`, but the question/description is asking you to `return` the string. Currently, you are not returning anything from your function, so it will return undefined. You might also want to double-check by what they mean when they say "if the name is missing", do they mean it is an empty string or `undefined`?

Comment: I changed it to this but still have problem with null and else .

Comment: Use `if(name)`. Then it will work when the name is missing or an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```js
export const twoFer = (name = "you") => {
  return `One for ${name}, one for me.`;
```

This is called template literals when using the ` we can make a string with variables inside of it. and we can give our function parameters default values just like I did.

Answer (score 0):

export const twoFer = (name) => {

```
   if (name) {
        return("One for " + name+", one for me.")}
   else {
        return("One for you, one for me.")}}
```